# Can't get a json request to display on page. User need to select a value and send to the request

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I am currently developing a webisite that asks a user to select from a list either gold or silver, then pass it to the JS file that then make an API request to display the current value of the metal chosen.  The result should appear on the screen without having to reload the entire page. The problem is that when i load the page nothing is happening at all. The page should display the default value of silver when loaded.  Any help would be appreciated.

```js
(function($) {
    // var apiKey = '348e90c9b0fdb12a5e5ca407328ffdae';
    // var apiURI = 'http://apilayer.net/api';

    // set endpoint and your access key

    endpoint = 'live'
    access_key = '348e90c9b0fdb12a5e5ca407328ffdae';

    //code the quote function 
    function quote() {
      //set variable for use in the JSON request.
      var type = $('#type').val(),
        //add USD to the end of the variable string, since format had the first 3 letters as the base for converting
        type = type + 'USD',

        // get the most recent exchange rates via the "live" endpoint:
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://apilayer.net/api/' + endpoint + '?access_key=' + access_key,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json) {

              // exchange rata data is stored in json.quotes
              alert(json.quotes.(type);

                // source currency is stored in json.source
                alert(json.source);

                // timestamp can be accessed in json.timestamp
                alert(json.timestamp);

              }
            });

          complete: function(req, textStatus) {

            switch (req.status) {

              case 404:
                showError('User requested a resource which does not exist!');
                break;
              case 101:
                showError('User did not supply am access key!');
                break;
              case 103:
                showError('User requested a non-existent API function!');
                break;
              case 104:
                showError('User has reached or exceeded their plan monthly API reqquest allowance');
                break;
              case 105:
                showError('User subscription does not support API Function');
                break;
              case 106:
                showError('User Query did not find any results');
                break;

              default:
                break;
            }
          }
        });
  }
  // event handler for when the convert button is selected
  // event handler: document is ready/finished loading
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // event handler: form submit
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
      // prevent form submission
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    // event handler: search button click
    $('#quote').click(function(e) {
      search();
    });

    search();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- jquery js file from JQuery.com -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- script to run Coin function-->
<script src="coin.js"></script>

<header>
  <h1>Silver & Gold Value</h1>
</header>
<!-- Introduction to the purpose of the program-->
<h2>Purpose</h3>
  I am a big coin collector, and go to a lot of auctions. And most of the coins i purchase are made of either gold or Silver. A lot of time the only value a coin had is the amount of gold or silver the coin contains. This is whats know as a "Junk Coin".
  This page hopes to help in knowing the current value of both gold and silver so that if you are ever at an auction or need to know the current value of a coin, the information is readily available.
  <h2>Find Value</h2>
  Select either gold or silver from the list to find its up-to-date value.
  <!-- create a form that holds the list of the 2 metal options-->
  <Form id="metal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="currencies" for="type">Select a Metal:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="type" name="type">
        <option value='XAG' title='Silver (troy ounce)'>Sliver</option>
        <option value='XAU' title='Gold (troy ounce)'>Gold</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary type currencies" id="quote">Convert</button>
  </form>


  <h2>Results</h2>

  <div id="results" class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center"></div>
  </main>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you everyone

Comment: Open your console. It's saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` You have a syntax error after `type = type + 'USD',` remove the comma. In general, if you load a site and nothing is happening at all and the page remains empty, it's a JS error and your console tells you what's going on.

Comment: Jeremy is right, you first need to learn how to debug your pages. For ajax stuff, the Network tab in the developer tools is also very informative.